# (Binary Search) Number of iterations needed to find an integer between an interval

Tags: c++, binary-search

**Description:**
I'm asked to determine the number of steps needed to find 'k' in [a,b] using Binary Search. The output should be the number of iterations needed to find 'k' represented by 'count'. I'm asked to do it without the built-in function.

**Problem:**
It seems like there's a logic error as when I enter my code on Codeforces for validation it gets rejected. The rejection comes from sample input that is unknown to me, I can't get my hands on the problem. Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
      /*a: interval start, b: interval end, k: number being searched for*/
      int a, b, k, count = 0;
      cin >> a >> b >> k;

      //Binary search variables
      int start = a, end = b, mid = -1;

    //Binary Search implementation
    while (start <= end) {
    count++;
    mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (mid == k) {
        cout << count;
        break;
    }
    else if (mid < k) {
        start = mid + 1;
    }
    else {
        end = mid - 1;          
       }
   }

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Hint:  Each iteration divides the quantity by 2.  The algorithm stops when the region quantity is less than 2 or the item is found.  Looks like a math issue.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews So,I've tried adding an if statement to the count++ to prevent it from counting an extra iteration. but it had an effect on the number of iterations for let's say the input: 1 10 7? Isn't the right answer for this input 4? and for an input: 1 1 1: 0? I'm confused.